# react-native-config use env inside .json file located at android folder

Tags: react-native, react-native-config

[Documentation](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) contains example for android native usage only for .xml and java classes. I'm having file 'msal_config.json' located at **android/app/src/main/assets** folder. Is there any way for me to access env's inside .json file?
For e.g my env is called: **AZURE_CLIENT_ID**